# How to abbreviate(ca) normal command with "Esc" and "Enter" key?

Tags: command-line, normal-mode

Yesterday I'm trying to make a doc command abbreviation for python.

The original command is `normal 0i"""^M"""`, which works in command-line mode.
But failed when using alias `doc` defined by `ca doc normal 0i"""^M"""`.

And later, I find I need to quit insert mode, do some movement, and then enter insert mode again.
The command `normal 0i"""^[$a^M"""` failed both in command-line mode and with alias.

How should I deal with `^M` and `^[` in normal command alias,
and how should I manipulate insert mode quit and enter again action with normal command?

PS: The `^M` and `^[` character was made by combining `CTRL-V` + `Enter`/`Esc`.

Comment: "Command mode" is a synonym for "normal mode". Did you mean "command-line mode"?

Comment: @romainl, yes, it should be `command-line mode`, I've edited the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And later, I find I need to quit insert mode, do some movement, and then  ...

I'm not sure where you found that from, but it's the other way around - you should quit insert mode before ending a `:normal` command, otherwise `:normal` will cancel the last operation. From [`:h :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal):

```
{commands} should be a complete command.  If
{commands} does not finish a command, the last one
will be aborted as if <Esc> or <C-C> was typed.
This implies that an insert command must be completed
(to start Insert mode, see :startinsert).  A ":"
command must be completed as well.  And you can't use
"Q" or "gQ" to start Ex mode.
```

Now, your original command:

```
ca doc normal 0i"""^M"""
```

using an abbreviation instead of a proper command, `^M` will be taken assumed to end the `normal` command (the way it would be if you'd actually typed it), and not be a part of it. Then you'd have to do:

```
ca doc normal 0i"""<cr>"""
```

Use [the `<cr>` code](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map_return) available for maps and abbreviations.
Though I think you'd be better off using a normal-mode map instead of using a command-mode one. Or use a proper command:

```
command! Doc normal 0i"""<cr>"""
```

Then you can use the `:Doc` command.

Comment: Excellent answer, is there such a mapping to `Esc` just as `<cr>` to `Enter`? Is there a vim help command that can view all such mappings?

Comment: @Zen indeed there is: `<esc>`. (See the first example in [`macro.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#macro).)